# how i can make game in javascript with point?

Tags: javascript

wlecome

i have this code to make emelent(spaceship) move by arrow key

i need to make Mines Down from the top and player must He avoids it ؟

anybody can help me to finish this game please ? small hint

this is my code

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
switch (e.which){
case 37:    //left arrow key
    $(".box").finish().animate({
        left: "-=50"
    });
    break;
case 38:    //up arrow key
    $(".box").finish().animate({
        top: "-=50"
    });
    break;
case 39:    //right arrow key
    $(".box").finish().animate({
        left: "+=50"
    });
    break;
case 40:    //bottom arrow key
    $(".box").finish().animate({
        top: "+=50"
    });
    break;
}
```

});

Comment: Please try to explain what is missing in your game. Do you need some kind of collision detection? Do have a _model_ of your game area or should it work without?

Comment: I have posted you a small hint the realm of a working game see my fiddle and answer. This should help you get things going in the right direction and show you how to take it from your simple implementation to a working game.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve all the things, you need to make a game. You need a little more code to be able to create a player space ship and a bunch of falling mines.

The most important thing is some sort of sprite class that can be spawned in the game area, the sprites are the player and the mines. They need to be moveable and they need to able to detect collisions.

The basics are when you move something check if it hits something. In a simple CSS game such as yours, collision detection is done with bounding rectangles. IE is a rectangle inside another one.

To explain how a game such as your planning is done, we would need a mini-book. Thankfully we have js fiddle and thankfully I have put together a very simple demo of what you are trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sprites = [];
  var enemies = [];
  var game = $("#spelplan");
    var STOP;

  // random numbers ints from min-max, use for points system
  function RND(min, max) {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }

  //
  // We spin up a simple sprite class that can be re-used, It's simple
  // params; id,x,y,w,h,class,area
  // The area is the realm where the sprite exists - in our case all in one div.
  // this would allow you to bind sprites into different realms - areas of your game.
  // methods: up, down, left,right - binding the sprite within the realms box x,y,w,h
  //
  // Exercise:
  // Modify, extend the sprite class so we can specify how much a sprite can move ie 20px or 10px.
  //
  var sprite = function(id, x, y, w, h, _class, view, collisionDetect, options) {
    this.view = view;
    this.id = id
    this.x = x + "px";
    this.y = y + "px";
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    //
    // Now we can pass in custom attributes for our sprites like PTS
    //
    this.options = options;

    this.el = $("<div id='" + this.id + "' class='" + _class + "'></div>").css('left', this.x).css('top', this.y);
    view.append(this.el);

    this.x = function() {
      return this.el.position().left;
    }
    this.y = function() {
      return this.el.position().top;
    }

    this.up = function() {
      if (this.y() > 0) {
        this.el.animate({
          top: '-=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }
    };
    this.down = function() {
      if (this.y() < this.view.height() - this.height) {
        this.el.animate({
          top: '+=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    };
    this.left = function() {
      if (this.x() > 0) {

        this.el.animate({
          left: '-=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }
    };
    this.right = function() {
      if (this.x() + this.width < this.view.width()) {
        this.el.animate({
          left: '+=25px'
        }, 0);
        if (collisionDetect) collisionDetect(this);
      }
      this.destroy = function() {
        // remove from dom
        this.el.remove();

        // remove sprite from sprites
        for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
          if (data[i].id == this.id) {
            sprites.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }



        }

      }

    };
    // returns back the x,y's and the z's of a sprites
    this.getPos = function() {
      var pos, width, height;
      pos = this.el.position();
      width = this.el.width();
      height = this.el.height();
      return [
        [pos.left, pos.left + width],
        [pos.top, pos.top + height]
      ];
    };
    // checks if any two positions are a collision
    this.comparePos = function(p1, p2) {
      var r1, r2;
      r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
      r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
      return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    };
    // returns true if the passed sprites collides with this sprite
    this.collidesWith = function(sprite) {
      //
      // Ignore any sprites that are "destroying" themselves!
      //
      if (sprite.destroyed === true) return;

      var pos1 = this.getPos(),
        pos2 = sprite.getPos();
      return this.comparePos(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && this.comparePos(pos1[1], pos2[1]);
    };

    // Calls custom init cb, this allows custom code when the sprite is
    // created.
    if (this.options && this.options.init) this.options.init(this);


    // add to our sprite object so we can reference.
    sprites.push(this);



  };
  //
  // Your existing spawn, now it just calls my sprite class with new and the params for our enemy.
  // My class will remember all the enemies within its own internal cache sprites, this now makes
  // it easier for us to detect what is going on since now we can ref any sprite on the screen
  // sprites[0].up() moves the first sprite up.
  //
  function spawnrand() {
    //
    // Some game logic - a max of 99 enemies in our game, this prevents constant spawning.
    // STOP is when the game is over.
    if (sprites.length > 100 || STOP===true) return
    var points = [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
    var spelplanWidth = game.width();
    var spelplanHeight = game.height();
    var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * spelplanHeight));
    var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * spelplanWidth));
    // create enemy, store him in array so we can find him,
    // extend with free fall code;
    // 
    var enemy = new sprite("enemy" + sprites.length + 1, randPosY, 0, 15, 15, "rand", game,
      //
      // passed in collide detect
      //
      function(sprite) {

        if (sprite.collidesWith(player) === true) {

          // here its game over, mark plater as destroying
          STOP = true;
          player.destroyed = true;
          alert("GAME OVER");
          player.el.fadeOut(100, function() {
            player.destroy();
          });
        }

      }, {
        init: function(sprite) {
          //
          // Very simple free fall code, if down returns true the sprite is off screen so stop free fall
          //
          function freeFall() {
            if (sprite.down() === true) return sprite.destroy();
            setTimeout(freeFall, 200);
          }

          freeFall();
        }
      });
    enemies.push(enemy);
  }




  var player = new sprite("box1", 200, 200, 50, 50, "player", game,
    function(sprite) {

      // detect if the player is over an enemy.
      sprites.forEach(function(sprite) {
        // primitive but ignores the plater sprite since he is not an enemy!
        if (sprite.id !== "box1" && player.collidesWith(sprite)) {
          //
          // Here is where the action happens, animate the destruction
          // of your enemy - add up the score
          // TODO:
          // Add a destroy method to our sprite class, removes him from dom
          // and from our sprite array!
          //

          // This flag tells the game engine that this sprite is destroyed, since u will want it to animate
          // or play some sort of death animation, while it is doing this we dont want it interacting with
          // our player, we use a flag so the sprite collision engine can avoid it.
          sprite.destroyed = true;
          // Stops the spawn from self destructing!
          clearTimeout(sprite.selfDestruct);

          sprite.el.fadeOut(100, function() {
            sprite.destroy();
          });
          SCORE(sprite.options.PTS);
        }

      })


    });
  setInterval(spawnrand, 250);

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        // is game over player cant move.
    if (STOP===true) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
      player.left();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
      player.right();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      player.up();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      player.down();
    }
  });






});
```

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/erLv5rwb/7/

It's primitive but it demonstrates how we easily we can make mines by calling our sprite class, and again how easily we can detect collisons on the mines when they hit us.

To create a sprite we call

```
var player = new sprite(id, x, y, w, h, cssClass, realm,onMoveCB,options)
```

Id: element id for sprite
x,y,w,h: position and size of sprite in px
cssClass: any css to be applied to our element to create our sprite shape
real: the div that is the playing field
onMove: a callback that is called when the sprite is moved, here we can do our collision detection
options: allows us to pass in other stuff, like score, lives etc

We can move a sprite by doing

sprite.down(); //up left or right

and we can check if we hit something ie the player

if (sprite.collidesWith(player)===true) // make the player explode spawn a new one

It's primitive but it should give you some pointers to how a simple game is made.